# Adapt bash loop to be use in csh

Tags: bash, unix, csh

I am trying to adapt the loop code from bash to csh:

```
 while read file; do

   if ! UPLOAD_FILE=$(ls "$UPLOAD_ARCHIVE_DIR"/*$file* 2>/dev/null); then
     echo "could not find $file"
     (( MISSING_COUNTER++ ))
     continue
   fi

   ls -l "$UPLOAD_FILE" | sed 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *//'
   cp "$UPLOAD_FILE" "$PROCESS_FILES_DIR"
   DOS_FILE=$(basename "$UPLOAD_FILE")
   SOR_FILE=$(echo $DOS_FILE | sed 's/.dat/.sor/')
   unix2dos "$PROCESS_FILES_DIR"/"$DOS_FILE" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
   mv "$PROCESS_FILES_DIR"/"$DOS_FILE" "$UPLOAD_PROCESS_DIR"

   (( FOUND_COUNTER++ ))
 done < "$1"
```

The input information comes from variable $input and contains a list, here is a sample record from the list: PL000000002002638908

So far, I have tried to use foreach and while loops without success, any help is greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Why are you doing this? bash is generally considered to be a much better scripting language. (I'm not sure how well a `while read ...` loop can be emulated in csh.) See, for example, http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too broad. The question should be edited to ask specific questions about particular parts you're having trouble translating, rather than asking broadly about a large block of code.

Comment: @keith-thompson The reason why I need to use csh is because it is the only environment on the server and they have denied me using bash.

Comment: @john-kugelman I have specified the topic in question. Also, I have removed extra information from the code.

Comment: You are saying that `/bin/sh` on the machine is actually `csh`? I find that unlikely, and it would be much easier to make the `bash` code shown POSIX-conformant than to translate it to `csh`.

Comment: @chepner thanks, trust me when I tell you that the code for bash works perfect and this odd request is something unavoidable. It is pretty much csh or nothing :(

Comment: I'm distinguishing between `bash` and `sh`; I'm unaware of any Unix system that uses `csh` as the default system shell.

Comment: @chepner: There are BSDish systems that use `csh` as the default *interactive* shell (by setting `/bin/csh` as the shell in `/etc/passwd`), but `/bin/sh` should still be a Bourne-like shell.

Comment: Every unix has a Bourne-style shell as `sh`, almost always located in `/bin/sh`. It may be something more restricted than bash, but usually if bash isn't available then `ksh` is, and your script would work in either.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly *don't* need to translate your script from bash to csh.

`/bin/sh` is the Bourne shell, or something that works very much like it. This should be the case even on systems where `csh` is the default interactive shell and `bash` is unavailable.(On some systems, `/bin/sh` it may be a symlink to `ksh`, for example.)

`bash` is derived from the Bourne shell, and adds some bash-specific features.

You can confirm that `/bin/sh` is a Bourne-like shell by typing the following command at any shell prompt:

```
/bin/sh -c 'if true ; then echo Yes, this is a Bourne-like shell ; fi'
```

In the unlikely event that `/bin/sh` is really `csh`, the above will give you a syntax error.

It would be easier to modify your script to avoid bash-specific features than to translate it to csh. Read the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html), look for Bash-specific features, and modify your script to avoid them. (If that's even necessary; it may be that `/bin/sh` is something that supports at least some of them.)

Change the first line of your script to

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and see what error messages you get.

You might need to replace the

```
$(command)
```

syntax by the older

```
`command`
```

and this:

```
(( FOUND_COUNTER++ ))
```

to something using `expr`, perhaps:

```
FOUND_COUNTER=`expr $FOUND_COUNTER + 1`
```

The `while read file ...` loop should work as it is.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately this arcaic system is supposed to run csh, anything else is not allowed.

Comment: It's *very* likely that `/bin/sh` is a Bourne-like shell. The Bourne shell is *older* than csh. I've updated my answer to show how to confirm or disprove this, starting at the 4th paragraph. If `/bin/sh` really isn't a Bourne-like shell, what OS is this system running?

Comment: `$(...)` is supported by `/bin/sh`, backquotes will not be necessary. `FOUND_COUNTER=$(( $FOUND_COUNTER + 1 ))` is also supported by `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @chepner: It depends on the system. The original Bourne shell did not support either of those features. The OP says the system he's using is "archaic", so it's likely that `/bin/sh` is an older Bourne-like shell. For example, I'm currently logged into a Solaris 9 system on which `/bin/sh` reports syntax errors for both of those features. But it's certainly worth checking (which is why I said the OP *might* need to replace those constructs); if `/bin/sh` happens to be a bit more modern, that will save some work.